# Why PlaceRequest doesn't work normally as we expected (GWTP)?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I am using GWTP. There is a method to openURL as following:

```
public void openURL(int key){
     PlaceRequest request = new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.search).with("showData", "y");
     if(key==1){
         request.with("firstVariable","2154");
     }
     else if(key==2){
         request.with("secondVariable","4454");
     }
     String url =   Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setHash(placeManager.buildHistoryToken(request)).buildString();
     Window.open(url, "_blank", null);
}
```

There is a button to call `openURL(1)`, after clicking button it open a url in this form:

```
abc.com#search;showData=y
```

Clearly the above url missing the `firstVariable` param part.

The correct url should be

```
   abc.com#search;showData=y;firstVariable=2154
```

I don't know why GWTP didn't read the `request.with("firstVariable","2154");` part  as we expected.

Can you find out a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

request.with(param, value) returns new PlaceRequest, so

```
request = request.with("firstVariable","2154");
```

is what you need.